# Is there a way to undo calls in Amazon S3 if >0 have failed in CommandPools and Promises

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

To help clarify what I'm asking, let's consider the ability to do rollback in SQL transactions. This means that if I do 10 inserts to do the database, and even one fails, I can catch the exception and rollback.

The AWS S3 PHP SDK has awesome functions for concurrency, like Promises for async behavior and CommandPools to do batch requests. So is there a way to do this? Couldn't find anything in the docs. Do I just have to create the logic for this myself?

Comment: S3 is not transactional.  It's atomic (uploads succeed fully, or fail entirely), but not transactional.  You can't roll back actions on S3... so, it's not clear exactly what you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: So if even one `putObjectAsync() ` fails in a promise, it won't do the rest? I don't think that's true based off of the bottommost note [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/concurrency-in-version-3-of-the-aws-sdk-for-php/). Perhaps this is the case with CommandPools though.

Comment: Sorry, no, that isn't what I meant, but I can see how it could be misinterpreted.  When I said "uploads succeed fully, or fail entirely," I was referring to the fact that **each** upload **individually** succeeds fully or fails entirely.  Either it's uploaded and creates/overwrites an object, or it doesn't -- you can't accidentally upload part of an object.  Individual uploads are atomic.  There is no undo/rollback.

Comment: Ok, I see. I was thinking of a scenario where you would upload a bunch of files and then maybe you lose internet connection so the last one didn't go through. Using a Command Pool would mean that they're batched in one request, so it should be an all-or-nothing situation. But with Async, the same scenario could leave some uploaded and some left behind. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something. But I think I get that my desired behavior wouldn't be possible without custom logic.

Comment: A command pool is a cat herder that manages multiple parallel concurrent requests.  The uploads are still individual operations against the service API, independent and uncorrelated from the S3 service perspective.